# Memcached no get_hits

Tags: memcached

I have a problem with memcached on Centos 6 with apache on port 8080 and Nginx on port 80 as reverse proxy for apache.
I install Memcached to cache all static file :
Here is my memcached configuration for nginx :

```
server {
access_log off;
error_log  logs/vhost-error_log warn;
listen    80;
server_name  xxx.com www.xxx.com;


location ~* ^.+.   (js|css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf|pdf|ico|zip|rar|iso|doc|xls|exe|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|ogv|flv|mpeg|mpg|mpeg4|mp4|avi|wmv|docx|xlsx|pptx|3gp|7z|acc|gzip|img|m4a|m4v|mkv|mov|msi|chm|rm|w3g|w3x|log|dll)$ {
            root /home/xxx/domains/xxx.com/public_html;

            expires      max;
            set $memcached_key $uri;
            memcached_pass     127.0.0.1:11211;
            error_page  404 = @apache;
            access_log  /var/log/httpd/domains/xxx.com.log;
            log_not_found  off;
    }
```

Memcached is listening but there is no established session although i browsed the site for a lot of times.

```
Every 2.0s: netstat -natp |grep :11211                                                                                         Mon Mar  2 13:50:47 2015

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11211             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      10504/memcached
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:38126             127.0.0.1:11211             TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:38124             127.0.0.1:11211             TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:38144             127.0.0.1:11211             TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:38127             127.0.0.1:11211             TIME_WAIT   -
.....
```

Here is memcached statistic:

```
STAT pid 10504
STAT uptime 469 
STAT time 1425279094
STAT version 1.4.4
STAT pointer_size 64
STAT rusage_user 0.023996
STAT rusage_system 0.067989
STAT curr_connections 5
STAT total_connections 383 
STAT connection_structures 6
STAT cmd_get 145 
STAT cmd_set 0   
STAT cmd_flush 0
STAT get_hits 0
STAT get_misses 145 
STAT delete_misses 0
STAT delete_hits 0
STAT incr_misses 0
STAT incr_hits 0
STAT decr_misses 0
STAT decr_hits 0
STAT cas_misses 0
STAT cas_hits 0
STAT cas_badval 0
STAT auth_cmds 0
STAT auth_errors 0
STAT bytes_read 10726    
STAT bytes_written 181940 
STAT limit_maxbytes 1073741824
STAT accepting_conns 1
 STAT listen_disabled_num 0
STAT threads 4
STAT conn_yields 0 
STAT bytes 0        
STAT curr_items 0   
STAT total_items 0   
STAT evictions 0
```

There is no get_hit number while get_miss is going grow.
Please help me to figure out what is going on .
Thanks

Comment: There is no point in storing static file data in memcached. Linux filesystem cache is enough for that purpose, and it works automatically. Memcached cache should be stored to store the output of dynamically generated content, where it can save time by not forcing generation every time the page is loaded.

Comment: Furthermore, you should not use `root` inside `location` blocks, it only makes hard-to-diagnose side effects. Use `root` on the server level, and `alias` in `location` level if you need it.

Comment: I used OPcache to store query cache already but i see this thread provides a good way to improve the performance at : http://paulgraydon.co.uk/blog/2009/04/30/nginx-memcached-apache-light-and-fast-web-server-setup/

Comment: OPcache does not store query cache, it stores PHP code compiled into bytecode form, so that the PHP scripts don't need to be compiled every time page is loaded. And anyway, that article isn't that useful. You should serve static files using nginx only. In that article static file requests are passed to Apache.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your memcached server does not have any data in it (`STAT total_items 0`).
So nginx tried to lookup 145 items and failed to get any of them.

That is totally correct.
Nginx will not store anything in memcached with that configuration (actually I don't think it can do that, only with a non-standard module: https://github.com/bpaquet/ngx_http_enhanced_memcached_module).
So you need to figure out a process that stores data in memcached.

Comment: I used a script to cache all images file to memcached and now STAT total_items is 6294 .But no lucky with STAT get_hits 0
STAT get_misses 6976